# Can't create image from disk source in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Since today for some strange reason I'm unable to create a new image from an existing disk source of a closed VM instance. I used to create them daily, but for some weird reason the dropdown list of disks is empty. In the dropdown it states "There are no disks that meet the criteria".

I've been creating images from the same VM instance for months now but the problem started out today. For testing purposes I created a brand new instance, closed it and tried creating an image out of it. But no luck here as well, which leads me to believe that this is an error.

Anyone else having this problem as well? Whats the best way to contact Google if you don't have a support package?

Comment: There are no details in your question that we can review/reproduce/analyze. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) if you have an issue. Try to list your disk by command line, and to perform your operation with the CLI.